# Show that $P = Q^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

> Suppose $P$ is a positive semi-definite $n\times n$ matrix. Show that there exists a unique positive semi-definite matrix $Q$ such that $P = Q^2$.

In class we've been going over singular value decompositions of the form:

$A=USV^\dagger$

and we are recommended to utilize this to prove that statement. However I am having trouble understanding how two completely generalized matrixes can be related to the equation $P=Q^2$ without any more information.

Can anyone provide suggestions?

Comment: This might be of interest: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition

Comment: First: Suppose $P$ is diagonal. What do you think the matrix $Q$ would be in that case? Can you prove it is unique?

Comment: Second: Since $P$ is symmetric, how do you think $U$ and $V$ are related in its singular value decomposition?

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted?

Answer (score 2):

The singular value decomposition of a positive semidefinite matrix has a particularly simple form: $Q=USU^*$. Writing $S$ as the sum of $n$ matrices with at most one non-zero diagonal entry, we arrive at a geometric interpretation of this decomposition: $Q=\sum_{j=1}^n c_j Q_j$ where $c_j\ge 0$ and $Q_j$ are orthogonal projections on mutually orthogonal lines. Squaring $Q$, we find $Q^2=\sum_{j=1}^n c_j^2 Q_j$ because $Q_iQ_j=0$ when $i\ne j$. Therefore, for $Q^2$ to be equal to $P = \sum_{j=1}^n b_j P_j$, we must have $P_j=Q_j$ up to relabeling, and $c_j=\sqrt{b_j}$.